# Angular 7 ngIf materialize dropdown

Tags: angular, dropdown, angular-ng-if, angular7

I have a dropdown in angular with materialize and it works fine, but if I add for example *ngIf directive in a link dropdown-trigger, `ul.dropdown-content` class doesn't show anymore. Please help me what should I do to open the dropdown when I click on it. Thank you!

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s4">

            <a *ngIf="true"  class="dropdown-trigger" data-target="drop">Language<i class="material-icons right ml-0">arrow_drop_down</i></a>

            <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
            <ul id="drop" class="dropdown-content">
                <li><a href="#!">English</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">German</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Spanish</a></li>        
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove the ngif

Comment: but I need the ngIf to add a condition

Comment: What will happen when you click the link - your code says `*ngIf` always true you are making the anchor tag to display true always

Comment: then add the condition. Take note that it should be a boolean initialized in your typescript file. for example `show: boolean;` and then in your constructor `this.show = false` . then use `show` as your condition. I don't see why this shouldn't work

Comment: Yes, when the ngIf is true the link is visible, but when I click on it, the dropdown it doesn't open

Comment: try to create <ng-container *ngIf="CONDITION"> and put all the dropdown inside it and the close the tag. if still not working, try to remove data-target="drop" and add (click) with the function to control dropdown on click

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work with ng-container, but if I move the javascript dropdown materialize from ngOnInit to ngAfterViewInit, the dropdown works when I click on it and I don't understand why. Can you explain this? Thank you!

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const elemDropdown = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
  M.Dropdown.init(elemDropdown, {
    coverTrigger: false
  });
}
ngOnInit() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your `*ngIf` directive inside the `<ng-container *ngIf='true'></ng-container>` and your anchor tag inside the container, it might work - but the fact is `*ngIf` will remove the element directly from the DOM it does not hide the element from the DOM

If the above scenario didn't work use `[hidden]='false'` property binding and make it true if you want to hide the link - Just have a look https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ngif-case-study

Thanks - Happy coding !!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly install `ngx-materialize` after that you are able to use component like below

```
<mz-dropdown
  [id]="'dropdown-demo'"
  [align]="'left'"
  [belowOrigin]="false"
  [constrainWidth]="true"
  [dropdownButtonId]="'btn-dropdown-demo'"
  [gutter]="true"
  [hover]="true"
  [inDuration]="300"
  [outDuration]="300"
  [stopPropagation]="true"
>
  <mz-dropdown-item><a href="#!">One</a></mz-dropdown-item>
  <mz-dropdown-item><a href="#!">Two</a></mz-dropdown-item>
  <mz-dropdown-divider></mz-dropdown-divider>
  <mz-dropdown-item><a href="#!">Three</a></mz-dropdown-item>
</mz-dropdown>

<a mz-button id="btn-dropdown-demo" href="#">Dropdown</a>
```

More information you can find on that site https://sherweb.github.io/ngx-materialize/dropdown

More about `ngx-materialize` is here https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-materialize